# How to know when a window that where in background become the front most window?

Tags: swift, macos, nswindow, viewdidappear

I would like to know when a window that is in background becomes the frontmost window.

I read this question but it works to know what window is the frontmost and not when the window becomes the frontmost window: [How to know if a NSWindow is the front window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078655/how-to-know-if-a-nswindow-is-the-front-window)

I implemented this code but unfortunately it is called only when the window is opened not when it comes back to foreground

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    let a = variables.actionToAddToCurrentWorkflow
    if a != "" {
        actionItems.append(a)
        actionsListTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Being a beginner would appreciate a lot if it was possible to have a sample code as well.

Answer (score 1):

Observe the notification [`NSWindowDidBecomeMain`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419448-didbecomemainnotification). The object of the notification is the window which became frontmost.